# How to create PowerShell string interpolation when legal variable character follows the variable in the string?

Tags: powershell

I try to use string interpolation in PowerShell:

```
$myvariable = "World"
Write-Host "Hello $myvariable"
```

The code above works fine, writes "Hello World"

However in case if in the string the character follows the variable part forms a legal variable name, it cannot be parsed because of the ambiguity

```
$myvariable = "World"
Write-Host "Hello $myvariableimmediately continuing"
```

**Question**

I understand this should not work, but despite of googling I can not find such an example. What is the syntax I miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space is only one way to end a variable name.You can use brackets to exactly define the length of a variable in a string.

```
$myvariable = "World"
Write-Host "Hello ${myvariable}immediately continuing"
```

Comment: Thanks, minor correction: as I tried to find out, I experienced that not only space, but anything what does not qualify as legal character in variable name, like .,/( etc

Answer (score 7):

If you want run-on text to your variable, you can do it like this:

```
Write-Host "Hello $($myvariable)immediately continuing"
```

> Hello Worldimmediately continuing

The `$($variable)` construction is also useful if your object is multivalued and you just want to write out one value.

```
Write-host "My cat's name is $($cat.name) and he is $($cat.age) years old"
```

The parentheses are operating in basically the same way they do in mathematics - the expression inside is evaluated first, and then the result is parsed with rest of the statement.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the answer with {} syntax as it seems to shorter, but upvoted your too.